# "To work for" vs. "to work in" vs. "to work at"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, at-in, in-for

Is the preposition *in* universal in conjunction with the verb ‘to work’ and can it be used with any organizations and businesses?

For example:

> - He works as a cook **in** a local hotel near here.
> - He works **in** an office in Chicago.
> - She works **in** a big company.
> - She works **in** the emergency unit at the hospital.
> - She works **in** a shoe repair shop.
> - After leaving school, he worked **in** a restaurant for a year. military hospital.
> - His sister works **in** a bank.
> - She works **in** a shoe factory.
> - He works **in** a steel plant.
> - She works **in** a gift store on weekends.
> - Ann works **in** a research institute.

When should the prepositions *at* and *for* be used? For example:

> - Barbara works **at** a travel agency.
> - She works **at** the local supermarket.
> - Now he works **for** a bank.
> - I work **for** a small non-profit organization.

I’ve never heard:

> She works **for** a shoe factory.

But with a law firm it’s OK:

> She works **for** a law firm.

Why?

Comment: GR. May even be a non-Q: too broad.

Comment: If she is a lawyer or a salesperson, she can work FOR a shoe factory - she will not be making shoes

Comment: Are you asking because you're a foreign learner? If so, you should consult a suitable grammar book. If you're a native speaker, you already know how to use prepositions. All the sentence you give as examples are possible in English.

Answer (score 12):

No, the preposition **in** isn't *universal in conjunction with the verb **to work***. That's the answer to your question.

**In, for,** and **at** are used interchangeably in most cases.

> I work {**in/for/at**} a bank.

is a perfectly reasonable trio of standard and idiomatic sentences. They all mean that **I am employed by** the bank.

If one wants to qualify one's working conditions, one needs to say more, e.g.,

> I work **for** myself, but every day I take my notebook PC and work {**in/at**} the university.

**I employ myself**, but my working venue is a university library.

I used to work for a professor of Education. I worked **at** the university in his office, but I didn't work **for** the university; I worked strictly for him. I wouldn't  say that I worked **in the university** in this case: it doesn't take the same usage rules as **{in/at} the university library**.

Prepositions are strictly native-speaker knowledge-governed. Not everyone who speaks the same dialect (national or regional) uses the same preposition as everyone else. Sometimes one has to use the preposition that makes semantic sense (if something's sitting **on top of the table**, one must say **on the table**, not **by the table** or **under the table**), and sometimes not (**Let's walk {up/down} this block for a few minutes** , regardless of whether the block goes uphill or downhill or the numbers ascend from 0 to 100 or descend from 100 to zero).

Context is more important that business type, and idiomatic usage for one's regional or national dialect is also important.

Answer (score 9):

As a guide, you work *for* an employer, *in* a department, *at* a location. For example, you could work for Airbus, in the finance department, at the research facility.

It can get quite fuzzy though, because there is a lot of overlap. An employer name can be used to point to both the employer and the premises, at least locally where everybody knows the name, so "I work for/at Airbus" would both work. Similarly, where a business has only one function, the employer and the 'department' overlap - "I work for/in a restaurant".

This is why you have never heard "She works for a shoe factory" but you have heard "She works for a law firm." 'Law firm' points to both the employer and the premises ("There's a law firm on the 4th floor"), but 'shoe factory' points only to the premises.

Comment: ... or *in* a building or enclosed place, such as "*in* a bank".